# How to check for a substring in Django update_or_create() method?

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have the following object that I want to push to my database using the according model:

```
Object

{

'object_name': 'Foo',
'value': 100,00

}
```

and want to update the `value` of `Foo Bar` in the database.

How to make Django check for `Foo` being a substring of a database object (in this case `Foo Bar`) to avoid duplicates?

```
obj, created = foo_model.objects.update_or_create(
                    object_name=object_name,
                    defaults={
                        'value': value,
                    }
                )
```

(so the goal is to update the value of the object Foo Bar instead of creating a new object `Foo` since it is a substring of an already existing object).

Comment: Imagine that you pass the emty string, then this should update all records?

Comment: It is not hard if a substring exists to *rename* the model to that substring, but leaving it unchanged, that is harder.

Comment: In my specific usecase I only have like 200-300 cases caused by this problem where each substring contains at least 4 chars, still there might be bugs then but minimized

Comment: yeah, well personally I actually do not like thinks that "fail silently", since often it will later result in more trouble than it was in the first place, but that is of course a personal flavor.

Comment: totally agree, but the data publisher meant to use short terms for his stock companies and sometimes the long version (e.g. 'BMW' and 'BMW AG') which makes the scraping a nightmare... I then might replace the 'AG' substrings to get better data... finance APIs are too expensive still ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can not do this with a single `update_or_create`. We can perform an `update_or_create` that will also *change* the `object_name` in case of a match, for example with:

```
# changes the object_name of the object if it already exists
obj, created = foo_model.objects.update_or_create(
    object_name__contains=object_name,
    defaults={
        'name': object_name
        'value': value,
    }
)
```

but we can fix that by writing our own function with [**`.get_or_create(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

```
# does not change the object_name of the object if it already exists
obj, created = foo_model.objects.get_or_create(
    object_name__contains=object_name,
    defaults={
        'name': object_name
        'value': value,
    }
)
if not created:
    obj.value = value
    obj.save()
```

So here we update the `value` of the item in case it already existed.

That being said, I'm not sure that this is a good approach. It looks like you aim to solve an underlying problem by matching. But it is possible that although there is a match, that is a *false positive*. After all for an `object_name` with value `'123456789'`, there are already *six* matches with a string with four characters: `'1234'`, `'2345'`, `'3456'`, `'4567'`, `'5678'`, and `'6789'`, so it is not unlikely that you will get unwanted matches.

Comment: thank you for this approach and your concerns! very helpful

Comment: I just got one more thought. Is it maybe possible to use Fuzzy Wuzzy for the mapping between object names to use update_or_create in the end?

Comment: @Phanti: problem is that as far as I know, it has no ORM implementation, so that means we manually fetch all the elements, then iterate over it, to retrieve the matching element. So that will likely be very inefficient, since it scales with the number of elements in the database.

Comment: hm ok, numbers of elements will stay around 1.000. I might give it a shot since I have no other solution in mind